# angular scope mixup; trying to sort list by clicking item in another list

Tags: angularjs

I'm able to sort a list by an input field, to show goals by user. But I haven't been able to accomplish the same thing by clicking a name in a userlist.

Typing a student name into the input field works fine.

```
    <div id="goalcontent">
        <ul id="listheader">
            <li>
                <p>Student Name: <input data-ng-model="username"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="goals">
            <li class="{{goal.status}}" ng-repeat="goal in goals | filter:username" >
                <span class="goaldeadline">{{goal.username}}</span>
                <span class="goaltitle">{{goal.goal}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here's my ng-repeat for users. The ng-click is being used to set a class on the li that is clicked. That works fine. I'm able to capture the username on the click as well and get into the setSelected function. The class change happens fine, but then I can't get the username to sort the list. I'm sure it's a scoping thing, but I'm getting nowhere.

```
    <div id="usercontent">
        <ul class="users">
            <li  ng-repeat="user in users"  ng-click="setSelected(this)" class={{selected}}><span>{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here's my setSelected function.

```
$scope.setSelected = function (username) {
    var lastSelected = ''
    if ($scope.lastSelected) {
        $scope.lastSelected.selected = '';
    }
    this.selected = 'selected';
    $scope.lastSelected = this;
    username = (this.user.username);
    console.log(username);
};
```

Console correctly shows my username. But nothing I've tried has been able to use that to sort the list of goals.

Comment: make a simple demo in plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: I've created a plunker for you. Maybe you could update it to reflect your problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/Eo87qwavg7Kta8k8cN07?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Without using the setSelected function, I will do it this way: (assuming that username and users are in the same $scope)

```
<div id="usercontent">
        <ul class="users">
            <li  ng-repeat="user in users"  ng-click="username = user.username" ng-class="{selected: (username == user.username)}"><span>{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</span</li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

1- With ng-class you can conditionally add the class 'selected'

2- With the ng-click you set the username to the user selected. it's gonna change your input text, and will be used by your ng-repeat filter.

Hope I understood what you wanna know. I'm a bit confused by your setSelected function. Usually I don't use 'this' in a controller and I didn't really see that before.

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't affect the ng-repeat for the goals. Part of the issue is that I have to attach the username to a new goal when a goal is created. In my users repeat I've got user.username, but in my goal in goals repeat I've got goal.username. I'm unable to bridge the gap. (The 'this' comes from my experience with jQuery. Shifting to Angular with a jQuery mindset makes my head hurt, but it sometimes works mixed in.)

Comment: @charliemagee Best advice on how to use angularjs I can give you, is not to do it the jQuery way.

Comment: @bektite -- I'm trying to avoid it. Still slip now and then, especially when I can't figure out the Angular way and a mix of the two somehow works.

Comment: @luc-- The setSelected function sets the class and removes it from the  li that previously had that class. Your conditional didn't do that.